# Index Variable Rendering as Literal and Not as Value When Looping Event Listener Adds

Tags: javascript

Fellow Stackers.

I am attempting the following:

```
for(let i = 0; i <= promoObj.length - 1; i++) { 
    document.getElementById(promoObj[i]["note"]).addEventListener("click", 
    function(){ 
        onPromoView(promoObj[i])
    }, false);
}
```

`promoObj` is an object containing several arrays. `i` is the index of each array. When I run the loop shown above, `onPromoView(promoObj[i]` is rendered literally as `onPromoView(promoObj[i]` and not with the looped index number such as `onPromoView(promoObj[0]`.

How do I get the event listener to render with the actual index number? I've tried many ways and did much searching but nothing is working. Hopefully, someone here has the answer.

BTW, I prefer the solution in vanilla JS.

Thanks.

Rudy

Comment: What does `onPromoView()` look like?

Comment: rendered literally _where_, exactly?